# Jquery like DOM selection in Angular5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

Let's suppose we have Angular component whose content is provided as follows:

```
<component-A>
     <span class = "parent">
        <div class = "toBeSelected"> DemoContent</div>
     </span>
     <div class = "toBeSelected"> DemoContent2</div>
</component-A>
```

In **jQuery** if I need to select element by selector `toBeSelected`

```
$('.toBeSelected').click(function(){
    var clickedSpanTxt = $(this).html(); 
    console.log(clickedTxt);
});
```

Is there any library exists which helps in selecting nested DOM elements from the component.

As `@ContentChildren` of **Angular5** only selects **direct child** of the component by selector i.e. I can only select span with the class `parent` or only one div with class `toBeSelected`.

Is there any way to select both div with class `toBeSelected`.

Comment: What exactly you want to get?

Comment: angular usually doesn't manipulate the DOM but data

Comment: I want to add css class to that selected content and add event handler to that content.

Comment: @ShubhiSood then use ngClass and ngClick (or similar). Use Angular, not jQuery / Dom.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same callback function on both elements, or make `toBeSelected` another component with a callback function enclosed in it.

Read [this](https://angular.io/guide/user-input)

Comment: I not only want to add click handler but also add CSS class to that content. i.e. change the styling of content and manipulate the structure of content.

Comment: Ok, so add a callback function into your component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM APIs. As `document` is directly available in angular component (.ts file). So you can use

```
let elSelected = document.querySelectorAll(".toBeSelected");
```

that will return the array of dom elements.